# How to format Chapter Heading appearance on pages

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, fncychap

I want to have only the chapter heading showing on top of each page without the the section headings. Below is a MWE. How do I modify it to get rid of the section heading appearing so as to avoid the overlap of chapter and section headings on top of each page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in,right=1.0in,bindingoffset=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document}
 \chapter{Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Some Sections Some section1}
 \lipsum[2-3]
 \section{Some Sections Some section2}
 \lipsum[1-16]
 \chapter{Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter1 }
  \section{Some Sections Some section5}
  \lipsum[4-5]
  \section{Some Sections Some section6}
  \lipsum[6-7]
  \chapter{Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some      Chapter45}
   \section{Some Sections Some section6}
   \lipsum[4-5]

  \section{Some Sections Some section7}
   \lipsum[10-11]
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the commands `\rhead` and `\lhead`. The code for box around the header is took from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42454/92620).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in,right=1.0in,bindingoffset=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove header rule
\rhead{\flushleft\leftmark}
\rhead{\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{\leftmark}}} %make box on th header
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm} %add some additional space between header and text
\lhead{}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Some Sections Some section1}
 \lipsum[2-3]
 \section{Some Sections Some section2}
 \lipsum[1-16]
 \chapter{Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter1 }
 \section{Some Sections Some section5}
 \lipsum[4-5]
 \section{Some Sections Some section6}
 \lipsum[6-7]
 \chapter{Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some Chapter Some      Chapter45}
 \section{Some Sections Some section6}
 \lipsum[4-5]

 \section{Some Sections Some section7}
 \lipsum[10-11]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: good it works. However, instead of the  \fancyplain, is there any other command to get the fance boxes around the chapter headings? Thank you

Comment: You  should add that part to your question by editing it, the part about the box. `\fancyplain` has nothing to do with the box, what do you want exactly is a box on the header?

Comment: @richard please check if my update answers your needs.

Comment: sorry for my trouble. I meant the boxes on the chapter headings itself. The earlier one is fine except for the plain chapter headings in the text itself

Comment: I responded above

Comment: @richard the box is on the heading isn't? sorry i don't understand. or do you mean only on the text "chapter number"?

Comment: it's the main chapter heading that I wanted the fancy box around it. The "header" showing the particular chapter on each page is alright from the first the code you sent. Also can you explain why the actual chapter heading is toggled case but the header is CAPITALISED? Can it be modified to the toggled case i.e. only first letter capitalised or having the exact cases of letters from the main chapter heading. Thank you