how do I frame text so that it also moves to the next page if it is too long?
I want to be able to put a frame around my text in such a way that I can decide in the middle of the page to close the frame and start a new one, and in addition, so that whenever the text is too long to fit into the page, the frame closes, and begins again in the next page.
Basically, being able to frame text and wrap between pages.
Here is an MWE that doesn't work, because the text gets cut at the bottom of the page:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}


Have a look at the tcolorbox package. It has options to for breakable boxes.

This question is similar to: How to put a framed box around text + math environment. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470383/framed-boxed-text-with-continued-text-on-page-break, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42452/277964 and maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400330/multi-page-tcolorbox-with-complete-box-on-each-page

Off-topic: Be careful with line-breaks after {.

As mentioned by @samcarter the most popular, powerful package with excellent support for such purpose is package tcolorbox. But don't forget to also remove the minipage, because a minipage would prevent page breaks:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=white]% breakable framed box white background
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


or (with lighter rule at the split position):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=white,toprule at break=0.05pt,bottomrule at break=0.05pt]% breakable framed box white background
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


For more information about all the features please have a look into the documentation of the package.

Also not it might be a good idea to use an "open" box, so the reader know that the text continues on the next page.

@daleif Agree, but the OP wrote: “whenever the text is too long to fit into the page, the frame closes, and begins again in the next page.” So IMHO the question was explicitly for closed boxes.

Often the OP does not know any better. Like the users who always add vertical lines in their data tables.

@daleif OK, I've added a compromise solution. If the OP decides to remove the lines, (s)he should either read (sevtion 11.2 of) the manual or ask a new question.

Welcome to TeX.SE, simple method is using framed.sty, and the examples are:
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
...
%%full box for page breaks
\begin{framed}
...
\end{framed}

and 

%%%open top/bottom at page breaks
\begin{oframed}
...
\end{oframed}
...

Choose which one you likes, other supporting packages are mdframed.sty and tcolorbox.sty both packages are having nice documentation.
